# access properties using class forwarding in iOS

Tags: ios, properties

Suppose I have 2 classes:A and B.A has a 'name' property that I want to access in B.Now I have 2 ways to get this done:

1.Make a property in B and pass the value A's property to B' property in class A.
2.Another thing is that I can use delegation and get the value of that property in B.

ALso I know that when we try to access the property 'name' in B directly by writing the following lines of code,it won't work.

```
    A.h
@property NSString *name;
    B.m
A *ins = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"id"];
NSLog(@"%@",ins.name);//will give null
```

Now my question is:What is the reason for that behaviour?I mean when we pass A's property to B's property using B's instance in A,why can't we do the above thing?
What I'm assuming is that A is on the stack and it doesn't know anything about B.So,it doesn't give its property value to B.But I don't want to assume anything.Also,does it have any connection with 'class forwarding' concept.Any accurate explanations...

Comment: where you set the value of name parameter ? in class A or class B

Comment: in class A,and then directly accessing it in B(B is on top of stack) gives null.Why?

Comment: give the strong property to name variable.

Comment: its strong,nonatomic,readWrite by default

Comment: Nonatomic is NOT default behavior

Comment: Ya my mistake,its atomic :-)

Comment: so try with nonatomic and retain property

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96325/discussion-between-reckoner-and-jaimish).